# Convert string to 10 character string with leading zeros if necessary

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

I have the below data and am obtaining the expected output column for it.

```
DATA          EXPECTED_OUTPUT       EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          123      0000000123       7 leading 0s to get to 10 characters.
          nan            None       If data is not numeric, then null/None output.
         123a            None       If data is not numeric, then null/None output.
1111111111119      1111111119       If data length >10, truncate to right 10 characters.
            0      0000000000       9 leading 0s to get to 10 characters.
        123.0      0000000123       Remove decimal part and leading 0s to get to 10 characters.
```

I have 3 ways currently of doing so, but I'm unsure whether they are the optimal solution to handle all data possibilities.

```
# Option 1
df['DATA'] =pd.to_numeric(df['DATA'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).\
        astype(np.int64).apply(str).str.zfill(10)
```

```
# Option 2
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].map('{:0>10}'.format).astype(str).\
        str.slice(0, 10)
```

```
# Option 3
df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].astype(str).str.split('.', expand=True)[0].str\
        .zfill(10).apply(lambda x_trunc: x_trunc[:10])
```

Any help on how to improve the way of doing this will be truly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look through the answers to [Padding a hexadecimal string with zeros](/q/67611/75307), as it's a very similar problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sadly, I don't think that's going to buy OP a lot, since the pandas vectorized approach doesn't support the typical native approach.

Comment: @Reinderien, fair enough - I've never worked with pandas, so I'm speaking from a relatively ignorant position.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want the non-numeric case to result in `None`? Pandas more commonly uses `NaN`. Anyway.

You're missing an important test case: what do you want to happen for values with a non-zero post-decimal half?

Option 1 is broken because you're just substituting 0 for non-numeric cases.

Option 2 is non-vectorized due to the `map`, and will not catch `123a`; so it's broken too. As a bonus, your `slice(0, 10)` is slicing from the wrong end of the string.

Option 3 is non-vectorized due to the `apply`, and does manual parsing of the decimal which is slightly awkward; it's also not going to catch non-numerics so it's broken.

So I mean... if I were to be picky, none of your code is functioning as intended so closure would be justified; but what the heck:

One approach that does not break vectorization and meets all of the edge cases would be

- Call `to_numeric(errors='coerce')` as you do in #1
- For valid numerals only, maintaining the original index:

  - cast to `int` to drop the decimal
  - cast to `str`
  - `zfill` and `slice` (from the end, not the beginning)
- Save back to the data frame on valid indices only
- Fill the invalid indices with `None` (`fillna` is not sufficient for this purpose)

### Suggested

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        123,
        float('nan'),
        '123a',
        1111111111119,
        0,
        123.0,
        123.4,
    ],
    columns=('DATA',)
)
as_floats = pd.to_numeric(df.DATA, errors='coerce')
as_strings = (
    as_floats[pd.notna(as_floats)]
    .astype(int)
    .astype(str)
    .str.zfill(10)
    .str.slice(-10)
)
df['out'] = as_strings
df.loc[pd.isna(as_floats), 'out'] = None
```